# How much is that anyway?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

How can I tell which dollar amount is more than the other?  I can figure out many of them, Un, duo, tre, etc. are easy, as is oct, nov, dec, but some of them are just confusing.

Comment: What are the ones you are confused about? List them if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Adventure Capitalist uses derived number prefixes based on the original Latin terms. Essentially, they take the number of zeroes, divide it by 3 discarding the remainder, and translate it to Latin.

There is a table on Wikipedia that explains these prefixes. The table can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix.

As a further complication, this system also uses the German way of writing numbers, in that the smaller number is put in front of the larger number. So a digit with 63 zeroes (so 21 groups) becomes unvigintillion or something like that, I don't have the game handy right now.